# Nested states 2 levels down in Angular UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know how to use UI-Router to the level of adding routes and sub-routes, for example on my site I have a series of mail services:, as in `http://localhost:3001/#/partners/usps` where "usps" is a partner.  This is using:

```
 .state('partners.usps', {
  url: '/usps',
  templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.html',
  controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'USPS',
    access: 'public'
  }
})
```

What I'd now like to do is have URLs a level below this for different parts of this partner USPS, such as `http://localhost:3001/#/partners/usps/labels` and I can't find info on this.

This does **not** work:

```
  .state('partners.usps.indicia', {
  url: '/indicia',
  templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.indicia.html',
  controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'USPS',
    access: 'public'
  }
})
```

What's the syntax/method for this?

Comment: You added in the partner.usps.html the ui view directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, which part is not working as expected - so I [created working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Chdw36Lao9iUvoqLWnrc?p=preview).

States are unchanged:

```
  .state('partners', {
    url: '/partners',
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
  })
  .state('partners.usps', {

      url: '/usps',
      templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.html',
      controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'USPS',
        access: 'public'
      }
  })

  .state('partners.usps.indicia', {
    url: '/indicia',
    templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.indicia.html',
    controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'USPS',
      access: 'public'
    }
  })
```

And for a state `'partners.usps'` I use a template which serves as a target for a child as well:

This is the **templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.html',** - check the attribute on its root element

```
 <div ui-view>
  <h3>current state name: <b> partners.usps</b></h3>

  <h5>params</h5>
  <pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>
  <h5>state</h5>
  <pre>{{$state.current | json}}</pre>

 </div>
```

So, the child will replace this content completely

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Chdw36Lao9iUvoqLWnrc?p=preview)

NOTE: we can just extend parent, not replace, e.g

```
 <div>
  <h3>current state name: <b> partners.usps</b></h3>
  <div ui-view=""></div>
```

Extend:

Not sure what is the real requirement, But I extended the plunker.

Let's say we need to be able to navigate to links like these:

```
<a href="#/partners/usps">
<a href="#/partners/usps/indicia">
<a href="#/partners/usps/label">
<a href="#/partners/usps/any">
<a href="#/partners/usps/other">
```

Then this will do the job

```
// this is a special state INDICIA
// if needed, it could do some special stuff
  .state('partners.usps.indicia', {
    url: '/indicia',
    templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.indicia.html',
    controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'USPS',
      access: 'public'
    }
  })

// this will handle any other params, passed 
// as a child
  .state('partners.usps.child', {
    url: '/:paramName',
    templateUrl: 'modules/partners/templates/partner.usps.indicia.html',
    controller: 'PartnerCarrierCtrl as carrier',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'USPS',
      access: 'public'
    }
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzYwOAYjwZFvEe1SQmr0?p=preview)

Finally, I created an inlined plunker, with the extended version, which could be accessed here:

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/b5nGpGKcGtQNuIbIgxPD#/partners/usps/other111

and we can test that any param could be passed in the url: `#/partners/usps/what-ever-we-want`

Comment: plunker doesn't run:  "Unable to connect to any application instances."  Also, this isn't working for me.  If I repro what you have above, when I navigate to `http://localhost:3001/?#/partners/usps` it works, but `http://localhost:3001/?#/partners/usps/indicia` kicks me out to my login page.  Note, what I was trying to do all along is to have that URL: `/partners/usps/indicia`, `partners/usps/labels` etc.  If that's not possible, I can re-architect.

Comment: OK, I am not sure what you want. I thought my example is clear, and gives you answer... but ... I created updated version http://plnkr.co/edit/WzYwOAYjwZFvEe1SQmr0?p=preview (for me plunker is working), it should help...

Comment: And I also created special plunker here http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/b5nGpGKcGtQNuIbIgxPD#/partners/usps/other111 which should allow you to change url as you want and see it in action

Comment: I noticed I have a config file which might be breaking things: `angular.module('pb.partners').config(function($urlRouterProvider { $urlRouterProvider.when('/partners', '/partners/id'); });`  I was told this was needed.

Comment: Well, such redirection is breaking any other handling. As you can see in my examples, without that, we can do lot more precise state setting...

Comment: yes.  i wish the plnkrs worked for me (the editable ones) but I get that same error in Chrome, FF, and Safari.

Comment: Well, does not that mean that you should finally remove that BUG from your code? All will start to work, as I showed you. Right?

Comment: Yes, I will try it.  I apologize as I am inheriting an app from another dev and just finding things.  In fact, the app is 1.2.6 which probably explains my frustration.

Comment: I just wanted to say: I want to assist, I want to help if I can. And if it will mean something/anything to you. But Now I was lost... So, please, let me **later** know  1) if I can do anything else for you... 2) if it is ok... or 3) if I should remove my answer and let others to come here... Wish you make it ;)